# Why would I want to implement virtual functions without implementation in an abstract class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual

I am sorry but I have to ask a stupid question.
I understand the benefit of implementing an abstract class as such. If I have virtual function with a basic implementation that is always called in cases when the derived classes don't have a specific implementation there is definitely a benefit, e.g.
`virtual void ImplementedVirtFunc() {//do something basic}`

What I don't quite get is what is the benefit of implementing a purely virtual function such as
`virtual void VirtFunc() = 0;`

In this case my derived classes need to implement the specialisized function anyhow if they need it. But I could straight forwardly just implement it there and omit the `virtual void VirtFunc() = 0` line in my abstract class.

So is there a specific benefit for implementing `virtual void VirtFunc() = 0` that I don't see?

Please forgive me this stupid question. I started to learn C++ this January and I am still have a long way to go to understand all the subtleties...

Comment: `virtual void VirtFunc() = 0` is used when the base class has no implementation of the function and you want to force the derived classes to provide it.

Comment: *"But I could straight forwardly just implement it there"* - How? You're assuming there's always a way to implement a "basic version" in the parent class, you can find tons of examples where it's not possible (or it's technically possible but does not make sense).

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thank you! This is an excellent comment. This indeed could be a driver for this.

Comment: Sometimes, there is no reasonable default behavior you could implement in the base class.

Comment: Some consider that interfaces/abstract classes shouldn't provide implementation. so `= 0;` would be the rule ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42, I think it depends on the actual use case. An abstract class provides a framework, so there might or might not be some usefull default implementations.

Comment: A "funny" thing is that you can both declare a virtual function "pure" - thus requiring an override - *and* provide a definition for it in the same class. I can't remember if I've ever seen a good use for it, though.

Comment: @Devolus: some have clear opinions about that. I have a mixed opinion :-)

Comment: @molbdnilo it is indeed rare, but I have seen cases of a base class providing an implementation of a pure virtual method. Typically it is used when the base class wants to provide a common implementation that derived classes can call *in addition* to their own custom logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
virtual void f();     // virtual member function
virtual void g() = 0; // pure abstract member function
```

A class with at least one *pure virtual member function* is an *abstract class*, and cannot be constructed itself, which is often desired (only non-abstract, "concrete" if you will, derive classes should be able to be constructed);

```
struct Abstract {
   virtual void g() = 0;
};

struct NonAbstract {
    virtual void f() {}
};

int main() {
    NonAbstract na{}; // OK
    Abstract a{};     // Error: cannot declare variable 'a' 
                      //        to be of abstract type 'Abstract'
}
```

Abstract classes are typically used polymorphically, to allow dynamic dispatch to derived object methods:

```
struct Derived : public Abstract {
    void g() override {}  // #1
}

void h(Abstract const& obj) {
    obj.g();  // dynamic dispatch
}

int main() {
    Derived d{};
    h(d);  // Will result in invoke #1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> But I could straight forwardly just implement it there and omit the virtual void VirtFunc() = 0 line in my abstract class.

Sure, you could. But you wouldn't be able to call that method from your base class, since your base class doesn't know anything about its existence at all.

Consider the following example. Every `Shape` definitely has an area, even though not known for a general shape. And every subclass of `Shape` inherits the `Print()` method.

```cpp
class Shape {
  // ...
  public:
    virtual int Area() = 0; // there is no formula for the area of a "general" shape, but it definitely has one ...

    virtual void Print() {
      std::cout << "Area: " << Area() << std::endl;
    }
}

class Circle : public Shape {
  // ...
  public:
    virtual int Area() {
      // calculate and return circle area 
    }
}

class Square : public Shape {
  // ...
  public:
    virtual int Area() {
      // calculate and return square area 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect example case.  Nice job.

Comment: I was going to do the same answer but with `Draw()`. Good answer

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons.
One is to ***force*** the derived concrete class to implement your virtual function.
The second is to make your class an abstract class, which cannot be instantiated by itself.

Comment: The derived class is not forced to implement the virtual function, per se, only if it wants to be a non-abstract class itself (which is typically the case). Multiple interface inheritance is not uncommon (and e.g. [Google's style guide allows it](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Inheritance)), whereas multiple implementation inheritance is usually (preference ...) frowned upon, as compared to simply using compositions instead.

Comment: @dfrib: can you explain a bit what you mean with multiple interface inheritance and multiple implementation inheritance?

Comment: @ManyQuestions Say `A` is abstract, and suppose `B : A`, and `C : B`. If you never instantiate `B`, `B` doesn't have to override `A`'s virtual function. If you instantiate `C` however, you must override `A`'s virtual function.